# Byobu and Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, byobu

I'm finding that in Xubuntu 16.04 byobu is not behaving itself. I've used it for years on Ubuntu, most recently 14.04 with no issues and I don't know if the problems are the switch to Xubuntu or the upgrade to 16.

Specifically, the issues I'm seeing are that migrating between horizontal-splits with `shift-up/down` does nothing, creating a vertical-split with `ctrl-f2` does nothing and trying to resize two horizontal-splits with `alt-shift-up/down` does nothing. Perhaps there are more issues.

[image]
This is a fresh, out-of-the-box install of Xubuntu 16.04 and byobu, so I am wondering if others are affected and how this can be resolved?

I thought maybe another keymapping in Xubuntu, but so far I don't see any that overlap in settings.

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved this. The vertical split issue (ctrl-f2) was caused by a default Xubuntu key mapping, which was to do with switching between workspaces (just go to settings manager > window manager > keyboard and clear the Ctrl F2 key associated with workspace 2. Now you can make vertical splits in byobu).

The other issues resizing of splits (alt-shift-up/down) and switching between horizontal splits (shift-up/down) were fixed by altering the terminal preferences

[image]

by unchecking the "Scroll single line using Shift-Up/-Down keys" checkbox.

Comment: Good find.  So gnome-terminal is my primary terminal, and what's most thoroughly tested.  Other terminals are best effort.  Thanks!

Comment: @DustinKirkland would be useful to have some helper to solve that, or cli script to fix. So byobu can be installed and configured from shell.